# MUI Material-UI datePicker: How to prevent auto-selection to minDate on open?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to handle a case when initially loaded value is before the `minDate`. Originally when I open a date-picker modal it automatically reset its value to the `minDate`

Desired behaviour is it shouldn't set the minDate as date value itself. Instead the days before the minDate should be disabled

Here's my component:

```
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              minDate={minDate}
              name="releaseDate"
              value={releaseDate}
              type="date"
              onChange={onDateChange}
              autoOk
              onBlur={onBlurDateTime}
              placeholder="dd-mmm-yyyy"
            />
```

want to avoid writing custom rendering function, looking for a built-in solution